# Find the mocked component methods called not verified

Tags: mockito, junit5

I have a JUnit 5 test using Spring Boot 2.3.7 with Java 8:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class HourlyJobTest {

    @Autowired
    private HourlyJob hourlyJob;
    
    @InjectMocks
    AccountService accountService;
    
    @MockBean
    AccountRepository accountRepositoryMock;

    @Test
    void testAccountVerified() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        hourlyJob.verify();
    }
}
```

How can I find, in a clean fashion, the list of calls to methods of the mocked components that have not been verified (like in the test above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(hourlyJob)`.

It will print out in the Junit Console the interactions of the mock that have not been verified (Marked with ?). In Eclipse you can click on the lines that have not been verified and it will direct you to the position.

Comment: Actually, Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions expects a list of Mocks, not the tested component. Anyway, I can call it at the end with all the mocks from all the tests